# Selecting Textbox in a form

Tags: jquery

I have the following query:

```
$("input:text").somefunction();
```

How can I also include a button and Textarea in the above code without using classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:text` filters the inputs for text-boxes, so simply selecting [`:input`](http://&FilterField1=lookupTestField&FilterValue1=fsdf) will get what you're after:

> Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

note that this is a bit confusing: `$('input')` selects all `<input>` elements (buttons too, but not textareas), but `$(':input')` gets what you want.
, which takes just a single element according to structure of the whole document.
-->

Comment: Can you suggest how would I do it using class?

Comment: @ScG - if you can change the source, you just add a class the the elements you need, eg `<input class="Button SomeFunctionable">`, and select `$('.SomeFunctionable')`. Remember that an element can have multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can include extra elements by adding commas.

```
$('#myForm input:text:eq(9), #myForm input:button, #myForm input:textarea').someFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the usual approach of expanding your selector with commas, you can use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$('#form :input:text:eq(9)')
    .add('#form textarea')
    .add('#form :input:button')
    .add('anything_else')
    .somefunction();
```

Note however that `:input` alone will select all your form elements.

Reference: [:input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Comment: This is a bit backwards, if I may, you select all `:input` elements, break them by type, and join them back together. Also, there's no `:textarea` selector. Good tip about `add` though.

Comment: @Kobi, yup, thanks, you're right about textarea. Overzealous pasting. Fixed. Also I agree it's an odd way to do it, but I plopped in that last "anything else" line just to illustrate that it could be a nice way to accumulate a bunch of disparate pieces, syntactically.